# how to perform arithmetic operation to strings in java?

Tags: java, string

sorry for asking this simple question but i tried many ways still i am struggling to find 
solution. i have a 2 string variable  and i need to make addition operation for those string variable.

I tried The following Code:

```
String first="01.25";
String second="00.35";
Float f1=Float.parseFloat(first);
Float f2=Float.parseFloat(second);
Float f3=f1+f2;
System.out.println("value"+f3);
```

For Example:

String first="01.25";
String second="00.35";

Required answer is 01.60

How can i achieve  can any one help to fix this???

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem with your code above? Any error or exception?

Comment: Your code works fine in my computer. What errors are you getting?

Comment: the result of OP is '1.60' but he want '01.60'

Comment: The answers below _may_ be what you're looking for but they're only guesses because you did not describe your problem.  A good question has three parts:  A code sample that shows what you tried, a description of what you expected it to do, and a description of how its actual behavior failed to meet your expectation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following code:

```
String first="01.25";
String second="00.35";
Float f1=Float.parseFloat(first);
Float f2=Float.parseFloat(second);
Float f3=f1+f2;
String result=new DecimalFormat("00.00").format(f3);
System.out.println("value"+result);
```

**Output :**

```
value01.60
```

All you need is a `DecimalFormat` to format your result to required pattern. For more on `DecimalFormat` visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) link.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) object to format your number:

```
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat();
numberFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(f3));
```

Or initialize the instance with a pattern.

```
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
```